# OCaml Typechecking Problem When Using Two Parameterized Modules

Tags: ocaml, q, typechecking

I have two modules, Graph and Game, which are parametrized by other modules. They also contain functions f and g which cause typechecking problems when I use them in a testing module. I left out lots of the code that is not important for this problem.

Here is a Graph module that has some module `AbstractUSet`. `AbstractUSet.t` is used a lot in the original code. The function `f` shall later take another function and do some work. The problem is, that the other function comes from another module and has a different type.

```
module UTYPE = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end

module type GRAPH = sig
  module U : UTYPE
  module AbstractUSet : Set.S
  val f : (AbstractUSet.t -> AbstractUSet.t) -> AbstractUSet.t -> AbstractUSet.t
end

module Graph (UA : UTYPE) : (GRAPH with module U=UA) = struct
  module U=UA
  module AbstractUSet = Set.Make(struct type t=U.t let compare=U.compare end)
  let f g uset = g uset
end
```

The other module is the `Game` module. It does lots of things with `AbstractVSet.t`. It contains the function `g` that shall later be input for the function `f` from the `Graph` module.

```
module type GAME_PIECE = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end

module type GAME = sig
  module P : GAME_PIECE
  module AbstractVSet : Set.S
  val g : AbstractVSet.t -> AbstractVSet.t
end

module GameInstance (NA : GAME_PIECE) : (GAME with module P=NA) = struct
  module P = NA
  module AbstractVSet = Set.Make(struct type t=P.t let compare=P.compare end)
  let g vset = vset
end
```

And this is my module for testing. In the very end, both `UTYPE` and `GAME_PIECE` are the same, but I can't make that clear to OCaml. I've commented the lines that don't typecheck. The compiler says there are clashes between `MyGame.AbstractVSet.t` and `MyGraph.AbstractUSet.t`.

```
module TestGame = struct
  include(Game(struct type t=string let compare=compare end))
end

module TestGraph = struct
  include(Graph(struct type t=string let compare=compare end))
end

module Test = struct
  module MyGame = TestGame
  module MyGraph = TestGraph
  let stringlist = ["a";"b"]
  let uset = MyGraph.uset_from_ulist stringlist // works fine
  let vset = MyGame.vset_from_vlist stringlist // works fine
  let result = MyGraph.f (MyGame.g) vset // does not typecheck!
end
```

If you ask, why I'm using so many modules: The project is a lot bigger than this code extract, and it is intended to be like this ;)
Can anyone help me how I can make it clear to the OCaml compiler that both `UTYPE` and `GAME_PIECE` are the same in the `Test` module?? 
Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that your abstract set modules *are* different: the result of two functor applications in OCaml are only equals if the functor applications are applied to exactly the same *named* modules. For instance, in

```
module A = struct type t = int end
module F(X:sig type t end) = struct type t end
module FA = F(A)
module B = A
module FA' = F(B)
module C = F(struct type t end)
```

The types `FA.t` and `Fa'.t` are the same

```
let f (x:FA.t): FA'.t = x
```

But the types `C.t` and `FA.t` are different:

```
let f (x:C.t): FA'.t = x
Error: This expression has type C.t but an expression was expected of type
         FA'.t
```

But this part can be fixed by not using anonymous structure when they are unnecessary:

```
module Graph (UA : UTYPE) : (GRAPH with module U=UA) = struct
  module U=UA
  module AbstractUSet = Set.Make(U)
  let f g uset = g uset
end
```

Then, you are left with the "problem" that `Game(M).AbstractUSet` and 
`Graph(M).AbstractUSet` defines two distinct types. (Note that this probably the right behavior outside of tests). For the test, one option is to simply expose the information that those modules are the result of functor applications. For instance, one can redefine the `GAME` module type (and `GameInstance` functor) to:

```
module type GAME = sig
  type set
  module P : GAME_PIECE
  module AbstractVSet: Set.S with type t = set
  val g : AbstractVSet.t -> AbstractVSet.t
end

module GameInstance (NA : GAME_PIECE) :
(GAME with type set:= Set.Make(NA).t and module P=NA) = struct
  module P = NA
  module AbstractVSet = Set.Make(NA)
  let g vset = vset
end
```

Here, we have ketp the information that `GameInstance(M).AbstractVSet.t` is the
same type as `Set.Make(M).t`.

Combined wit the same operation on the graph part:

```
module type GRAPH = sig
  type set
  module U : UTYPE
  module AbstractUSet : Set.S with type t = set
  val f : (AbstractUSet.t -> AbstractUSet.t) -> AbstractUSet.t -> AbstractUSet.t
end

module Graph (UA : UTYPE) :
(GRAPH with type set := Set.Make(UA).t and module U=UA) = struct
  module U=UA
  module AbstractUSet = Set.Make(UA)
  let f g uset = g uset
end
```

we are preserving enough type information to keep the equality for the test:

```
module TestGame = GameInstance(String)
module TestGraph = Graph(String)

module Test = struct
  module MyGame = TestGame
  module MyGraph = TestGraph
  let result vset = MyGraph.f (MyGame.g) vset (* does typecheck *)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation :D

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem with polymorphic variants and functors - could you maybe have a look at it? I'd be very grateful! [Here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815196/ocaml-typechecking-problem-with-functors-and-polymorphic-variants)