# OCaml Typechecking Problem With Functors and Polymorphic Variants

Tags: types, module, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I have a problem using functors in OCaml. I have a module type `TASK` that is used to have different kinds of tasks:

```
module type TASK = sig
  type task_information
  type task_information_as_lists

  type abstract_u_set_type
  module AbstractUSet : Set.S with type t = abstract_u_set_type

  val mk_task_information : task_information_as_lists -> task_information
end
```

A module of type `TASK` will contain algorithms that use nodes. These nodes will have different types. I therefore built `TASK_NODE`:

```
module type TASK_NODE = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val to_string : t -> string
end
```

`task_information_as_lists` from `TASK` will be a list containing different types, but every task will have different types in that list. As I cannot have something like `module Game : (TASK with with type u := int list)` with functors, I've created a module type `INFO_CARRIER`. For every different module of type `TASK` I want to have a different module of type `INFO_CARRIER` that will hold the information what type `task_information_as_lists` actually is.

This is the module type `INFO_CARRIER`:

```
module type INFO_CARRIER = sig
  module INODE : TASK_NODE
  type u = [`V of INODE.t list | `E of INODE.t] list
end
```

For testing, I want to have `string` `TASK_NODES`, and an `INFO_CARRIER` that can convey a type u like `` type u = [`V of string list | `E of string] list ``.

So I built `StringTaskNode` and `StringInfoCarrier`, and also a `StringTask` to use the nodes:

```
module StringTaskNode : TASK_NODE = struct
  type t = string
  let compare = compare
  let to_string s = "Node " ^ s
end

module StringInfoCarrier (TN : TASK_NODE) : (INFO_CARRIER with module INODE = TN) = struct
  module INODE = TN
  type u = [`V of TN.t list | `E of TN.t] list
end

module StringTask (TN : TASK_NODE) (IC : INFO_CARRIER with module INODE = TN) : 
  (TASK with type task_information_as_lists := IC.u with type abstract_u_set_type := Set.Make(IC.INODE).t) = struct
  module N = IC.INODE
  module AbstractUSet = Set.Make(IC.INODE)

  type task_information = {v_nodes : AbstractUSet.t ; e_nodes : N.t}

  let mk_task_information info_list =
    match info_list with
    | (`V v)::(`E e)::[] -> {v_nodes = AbstractUSet.of_list v ; e_nodes = e;}
    | _ -> raise .... (* raising an error here *)
end
```

I then have another module `ProdFP` that will do some computation for a task:

```
module ProdFP 
  (TN : TASK_NODE) 
  (IC : INFO_CARRIER with module INODE=TN) 
  (TA : TASK with type abstract_u_set_type:=u with type task_information_as_lists:=IC.u) = struct
  ...
end
```

So far, no errors happen. But when I bring everything together in `Test`, I get:

```
Error: This expression has type
  [`E of string | `V of string list]
but an expression was expected of type
SIC.u = [`E of SIC.INODE.t | `V of SIC.INODE.t list]
Type string is not compatible with type
  SIC.INODE.t = STN.t
```

This is the testing module:

```
module Test = struct
  module STN = StringTaskNode
  module SIC = StringInfoCarrier(STN)
  module ST = StringTask(STN)(SIC)
  module PF = ProdFP(STN)(SIC)(ST)

  let v_list =["a";"b"]
  let e = "c"
  let info_as_list = [`V v_list ; `E e]

  let info = ST.mk_task_information info_as_list (* THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS *)
end
```

I know, this is a very long post, but I've tried to include as much information as necessary.
It would be so great if you could help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is just the signature constraint in the definition of the `StringTaskNode` module:

```ml
module StringTaskNode : TASK_NODE = struct
...
end
```

This constraint makes the type `StringTaskNode.t` abstract and thus hides the equality `STN.t = string`. Removing the constraint,

```ml
module StringTaskNode = struct
...
end
```

should resolve this specific issue.